# Insert update delete trigger in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, triggers

I have a windows application form. The table is called `messages` and whenever user inserts updates or deletes a message, the date/timestamp is stored in the column `UserAction`.

This column information should be retrieved and shown in the UI as a link. Clicking that link has an action and the link should be seen as read.

Can someone help me in giving some ideas to achieve this action?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you can trigger the event from database and display the details in the UI but I think below is doable:

1. Add `INSERT/DELETE` triggers in your table with the code to insert data in `UserAction` table.
2. Build an UI which reads the data from `UserAction` and displays in the `UI`.
3. You may want to refresh your `UI` to refresh the data from database `UserAction` at certain interval.

This way, you UI will poll for any changes `UserAction` at certain interval and refresh the page with refreshed data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175110%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), although there are some limitations to what can be monitored.

> SQL Server 2005 introduced query notifications, new functionality that allows an application to request a notification from SQL Server when the results of a query change. Query notifications allow programmers to design applications that query the database only when there is a change to information that the application has previously retrieved.

This functionality is exposed via the [`SqlDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) class. You should review the *Remarks* section as part of evaluating whether Query Notifications are for you:

> `SqlDependency` was designed to be used in ASP.NET or middle-tier services where there is a relatively small number of servers having dependencies active against the database. It was not designed for use in client applications, where hundreds or thousands of client computers would have `SqlDependency` objects set up for a single database server. If you are developing an application where you need reliable sub-second notifications when data changes, review the sections *Planning an Efficient Query Notifications Strategy* and *Alternatives to Query Notifications* in the *Planning for Notifications* topic in SQL Server Books Online.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trMessagesUpdateTimeStamp
ON dbo.Messages
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE 
AS 

  UDPATE dbo.Messages
  SET UserAction = GETDATE()
  FROM Inserted i
  WHERE dbo.YourTableHere.ID = i.ID
```

Points to check out:

- the `INSERT` case could easily more easily be handled by a `DEFAULT` constraint on the `UserAction` column - that way, upon `INSERT` the defined default value (e.g. `GETDATE()`) would be inserted
- you need to be able to join the `Inserted` pseudo table that holds all the rows that were modified by the last statement (and this can be **multiple** rows) with the `Messages` table - I've assumed here that you have some kind of an `ID` column that serves as primary key on `Messages` - adapt this as needed.

This handles the database part of the story - I'm not quite sure from your question what you want to do in the UI ...